# Length of string in Perl independent of character encoding

Tags: perl, string, unicode, character-encoding

The length function assumes that Chinese characters are more than one character. How do I determine length of a string in Perl independent of character encoding (treat Chinese characters as one character)?

Answer (score 9):

The [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) function operates on characters, not octets (AKA bytes). The definition of a character depends on the encoding. Chinese characters are still single characters (if the encoding is correctly set!) but they take up more than one octet of space. So, the length of a string in Perl is dependent on the character encoding that Perl thinks the string is in; the only string length that is independent of the character encoding is the simple byte length.

Make sure that the string in question is flagged as UTF-8 and encoded in UTF-8. For example, this yields 3:

```
$ perl -e 'print length("长")'
```

whereas this yields 1:

```
$ perl -e 'use utf8; print length("长")'
```

as does:

```
$ perl -e 'use Encode; print length(Encode::decode("utf-8", "长"))'
```

If you're getting your Chinese characters from a file, make sure that you `binmode $fh, ':utf8'` the file before reading or writing it; if you're getting your data from a database, make sure the database is returning strings in UTF-8 format (or use [`Encode`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Encode/) to do it for you).

I don't think you have to have everything in UTF-8, you really only need to ensure that the string is flagged as having the correct encoding. I'd go with UTF-8 front to back (and even sideways) though as that's the lingua franca for Unicode and it will make things easier if you use it everywhere.

You might want to spend some time reading the [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) man page if you're going to be dealing with non-ASCII data.

Comment: How would I use the substr function in conjunction with these chinese characters? I can now get the proper length with your third solution, but how do I use substr on the Chinese phrase? I'm actually trying to compare substrings of Chinese words (A and B) where I take substrings of B to see if it is the same as A.

Comment: @syker: `substr` operates on characters (not octects) so `substr` should work right if the strings are tagged with the right encoding. For example: `perl -e 'use Encode; binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; my $s = Encode::decode("utf-8", "长µ"); print substr($s, 1, 1),"\n"'` should give you "µ".

Comment: @syker: BTW, the first two example were illustrative, the `use utf8;` tells Perl that the script itself is UTF-8 so the "长" string is automatically flagged as UTF-8. The third one is the most useful in real life but I didn't want all the Encode business getting in the way of illustrating the connection between string length and string encoding.